# How do I filter results by object type in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to filter a list of objects by its type in PowerShell. I can, of course, use the type name and string comparison to do that:

```
PS C:\> gci -r | where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "DirectoryInfo" }
```

but having roots in C#, I was looking for something like the `is` operator.

Is my way the best, or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell has an `-is` operator:

```
gci -r | where { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't found it. LOL. Thanks a lot!